# How can I get the last ten rows in a Mysql database table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I use this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY id DESC limit 10";
$result = @mysql_query( $query );
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 print_r($row);
```

but it gets just the last row

Comment: what do you do with the query after this?

Comment: Possibly silly question, but: have you only got one row in your table? try select count(*) from info?

Comment: @butterchicken there are 28 rows

Comment: @Blair Conrad  I completed the code above .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) does not fetch an array of rows.

It fetches an array of columns from a single row.

To get all rows, you have to run it in a loop:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY id DESC limit 10";
$result = @mysql_query( $query );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        print_r($row);
```

Comment: how can I fetch the 10 rows ?

Answer (score 5):

The query is correct.  If you seem to be only getting one row, it's a factor external to the query causing it: either you only have one row in the table, or your application logic is hosed so that it looks like you only have one row.

Edit: Yeah, now that you've posted your code, we can see that it's that your application logic is hosed.  Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $rows[] = $row;
```